# Newtonsoft Deserialize error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize the below Json value but I'm getting this error.

`Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'error_report', line 1, position 66.`

Json Value I'm passing:
`{"form_typ":"R1","status_cd":"ER","action":"SAVE","error_report":{"error_msg":"File could not be uploaded! Download the latest version of Offline tool to generate the JSON file or ensure to validate your uploaded file against the template published at Specification Portal.","error_cd":"RET191106"}}`

Comment: Ho do you deserialize, how your object looks like?

Comment: The JSON per se is valid. Show the definition of the target object. I suspect `error_report` is defined as `string`, thus the deserialization does expect a `string` and not an object.

Comment: @derpirscher yes error_report was defined as string, thanks for pointing out. silly me.

now i'm using this class, and it works fine.

public class StatusInfo
    {
        public string form_typ { get; set; }
        public string status_cd { get; set; }
        public string action { get; set; }
        public ErrorReport error_report { get; set; }
    }

    public class ErrorReport
    {
        public string error_msg { get; set; }
        public string error_cd { get; set; }
    }